# Suggestion for finding patterns and replacing partitions in R

Tags: r, partitioning

```
n = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3)
```

I want to divide/split them into segments with every 3 integers and finds the pattern of each segment(A: all different, B: two identical, and C: all identical).

I did the partitioning with

```
par = split(n, ceiling(seq_along(n)/3))
```

but i am stuck with getting the patterns, any suggestion? 
I want to get something like

```
newn
[1] A C B A C C A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

count the number of unique values, then assign the letters:

```
par2 <- sapply(par, function(x) length(unique(x)))
c("C", "B", "A")[par2]
```

> ```
> [1] "A" "C" "B" "A" "C" "C" "A" "B"
> ```

If you don't want the final B (due to a length two vector), you can first do:

```
par <- par[lengths(par) == 3]
```

Comment: cool, didn't know the unique() function.. i can probably use it for the split as well...